# How to release object when using block callback

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, callback, objective-c-blocks

this is probably a newbie question regarding memory manegment.

How can i release an object when using blocks as callback in objective c?

(Updated code)

```
@implementation ObjectWithCallback
- (void)dealloc {
    [_completionHandler release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)doTaskWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))handler {
    _completionHandler = [handler copy];
    // Start tasks...
}
- (void)tasksDone {
    // Do callback block
    _completionHandler();
    // Delete reference to block
    [_completionHandler release];
    _completionHandler = nil;
}

// Use of the ObjectWithCallback
ObjectWithCallback *request = [[ObjectWithCallback alloc] init];
[request doTaskWithCompletionHandler:^(void){
    // Callback called and task is ready.
}];
```

Comment: What object do you want to release, and why can't you release it within the block?

Comment: What makes you think You can't rlese the object in the block?

Comment: He wants to release `request`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quick, incomplete answer: `[request autorelease]`

The problem with this is that blocks implicitly retain any objects that are referenced inside the body of the block.  So the block retains `request`, and `request` retains the block, leading to a retain cycle and nobody getting deallocated.

To remedy that, you declare your `request` variable as `__block`, which prevents the block from retaining the captured object:

```
__block ObjectWithCallback *request = [[ObjectWithCallback alloc] init];
```

Recommended reading:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html
- http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-30-dealing-with-retain-cycles.html
- http://castirony.com/post/3936227677/block-retain-cycle

Comment: __block should not be used in this cas.  The object's lifespan is clearly tied to the block and the block's retain ensures that.

Comment: @bbum I think I understand what you mean, but wouldn't this still cause a retain cycle if the block references `request`?  I guess a way around that would be for `ObjectWithCallback` to release the callback block after calling it.

Comment: Ahh -- yes -- different issue orthogonal to OP's question. Derp.

Comment: Thanks for the answers I'll dig into your reading tips. It seems like it could be an retain cycle. I thought i released the reference to the block from the object, but it doesn't seem to work (Code is updated)

Comment: Looking at your updated code, since you're releasing the block after it is called, you should be able to simply do `[request release]` inside of the block and have everything work correctly.  What happens if you do that?